# Access an element in an XML file and edit them using python

Tags: python, xml, edit

I have a rather sizable xml file that needs to be edited. I am trying to automate the editing process using python. I tried using the 'xml.etree.ElementTree' library in python but it seems like I am missing something. Can someone help me with accessing the elements in the file and how I can edit them?

Here is the xml file I am trying to edit.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:ScheduleDocument xmlns:ecc="xxx" xmlns:ns2="xxx/xxx" xmlns:ns3="xxx/xxx" xmlns:ns4="xxx/xxx" DtdVersion="5" DtdRelease="0">
    <ns2:DocumentIdentification v="xxx"/>
    <ns2:SenderIdentification v="xxx" codingScheme="A01"/>
    <ns2:SenderRole v="A11"/>
    <ns2:ReceiverIdentification v="xxx" codingScheme="A01"/>
    <ns2:ReceiverRole v="A11"/>
    <ns2:DocumentDateTime v="2023-02-23T0"/>
    <ns3:ScheduleTimeSeries>
        <ns2:CurveType v="xxx"/>
        <ns2:Resolution v="xxx"/>
        <ns2:ScheduleIdentification v="xxx"/>
        <ns2:ScheduleType v="xxx"/>
        <ns2:Status v="Confirmed"/>
        <ns2:ScheduleTimeInterval v="2023-02-05T00:00+04:00/2023-02-06T03:00+04:00"/>
        <ns2:LastModifiedDate>2023-02-23T01:22:13.167+04:00</ns2:LastModifiedDate>
        <ns2:IsDraft>false</ns2:IsDraft>
        <ns2:Parameter name="xxx" v="2.00000"/>
        <ns2:Parameter name="xxx" v="TEST_5_2_23"/>
        <ns2:Parameter name="xxx" v="TEST_5_2_23"/>
        <ns2:Parameter name="xxx" v="1"/>
        <ns2:Parameter name="xxx" v="0"/>
        <ns2:Parameter name="xxx" v="xxx"/>
    </ns3:ScheduleTimeSeries>
</ns3:ScheduleDocument>
```

I tried using 'xml.etree.ElementTree' library in python to read and parse the xml file but I did not have success.

Here is the code I built:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

PATH = Path(rf'C:\Users\{os.getlogin()}\yyyy\yyyy')


def XMLTree():
    tree = ET.parse(os.path.join(PATH, 'xxx', 'xxx.xml'))
    root = tree.getroot()
    tag = root.tag
    attr = root.attrib
    for child in root:
        print(child.tag, child.attrib)
    for i in root.findall('ScheduleTimeSeries'):
        print(i) # This prints nothing as I am not able to access ScheduleTimeSeries
    print(attr)
    for i in root:
        print(i.attrib)
    for j in root.findall('ns2:CurveType'):
        print(j)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting main')
    XMLTree()
    print('Main complete')
```

I am rather new to working with XML files. Can someone tell me what I am missing?
Can someone help me access the elements, say 'Status'. After accessing it, how can I edit it?

Comment: does your ns2:curvetype show a print? If so, maybe an ns3: is necessary before the time series?

Comment: I did not get the output but yes adding the xmlns before the timeseries got it to print the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple example:

```
root = ET.parse('your_path.xml')

# Finding
elem = root.find('.//{xxx/xxx}CurveType')
print(elem.attrib["v"])

# Editing
elem.set("v", "new value")
print(elem.attrib["v"])

# Adding
new_elem = ET.SubElement(root.find(".//{xxx/xxx}ScheduleTimeSeries"), "{xxx/xxx}NewElement")
new_elem.text = "added value"

# Writing
with open("ScheduleDocument.xml", "w") as f:
    f.write(ET.tostring(root).decode())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly. Just a quick follow on. Say there was another ns3:ScheduleTimeSeries with the same structure but the values inside it are different. Can we use for loop to loop over the two ns3:ScheduleTimeSeries and change the value of parameter, say 'Parameter'?

Comment: @AjithViswanath Yes, just use findall instead and loop through it. Same for parameter.